# Create PDF preview

Tags: c#, performance, thread-safety, cache

I have written the following `GetPDFPreview()` method. It open a PDF file, create a thumbnail (using `PdfDocument` class) and returns the result.

In order to improve performance, I have decided to cache the `PdfDocument` instance (to avoid reloading the file from disk and parsing it each time). The method is called from a service and the page indexes that will be requested for a given PDF  are not know in advance.

I want to make sure my method is thread safe AND there is no potential deadlocks. AFAIK there is two cases to take care :

1. Two threads could call `MemoryCache.Default.Get()` at the same time and if there is nothing in cache at that time both threads will load PDF from disk and both will call `MemoryCache.Default.Add()` (while only one should do that). I have added `pdfCacheMutex` mutex to prevent that.
2. The cache might dispose PdfDocument instance when it is currently used for creating the thumbnail. I have added `pdfDocumentMutex` mutex to prevent that.

```
Stream GetPDFPreview(string fileName, int pageIndex)
{
    PdfDocument pdfDocument;

    lock(pdfCacheMutex)
    {
        string cacheKey = ...
        pdfDocument = (PdfDocument)MemoryCache.Default.Get(cacheKey);
        if (pdfDocument == null)
        {
            CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy
            {
                SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                RemovedCallback = args => 
                {
                    lock(pdfDocumentMutex)
                    {
                       //it is necessary to dispose the FileStream 
                       //that PdfDocument is holding 
                       ((PdfDocument)args.CacheItem.Value).Dispose();
                    }
                }
            };

            pdfDocument = ...   //load from disk 
            MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, pdfDocument, cacheItemPolicy);
        }
    }

    var fileByteStream = new MemoryStream();
    lock(pdfDocumentMutex)
    {
        using (Image image = pdfDocument.Render(...)
        {
            image.Save(fileByteStream, ImageFormat.Png);
        }                   
    }

    return fileByteStream;    
}
```

Comment: AFAIK System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache is already thread-safe, callback won't be called concurrently

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti : the potential issue is not RemoveCallback itself but rather the consequence of `pdfDocument.Dispose()` being called while some other thread is using `pdfDocument` instance (eg : `pdfDocument.Render()` in `GetPDFPreview()`) . It will probably throw an ObjectDisposedException.

Comment: Not if you provide a factory delegate invoked by mc itself. Not a bug issue anyway...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti : which factory are you talking about ? Could you give more details. I checked all methods of MemoryCache and could not find anything that looks like a factory delegate or callback.

Comment: Sorry, that's another class I'm used to use! Mc has not a factory (which might be built using a custom CacheItem class) but callback is invoked after element has been removed from cache, no need to worry about its concurrent usage (sliding expiration isn't elapsed if a cache hit kept in use to build preview)